# Phalcon 4 update/insert/delete several row inside table on database

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using [Phalcon 4](https://phalcon.io/en-us) and I have a table `CompanyProduct` table that contains the foreign key:

```
companyId, productId
123        1
123        80
```

And I have to insert or update or delete the row of this table.

I receive from the front this:

```
companyId: 123
productIds: [1,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Is there a way to do it in one instruction? Or I have to use the transaction:

- open transaction
- delete all the companyId equal to 123
- insert the new elements
- close transaction

And for insertion of all the new elements is there an unique instruction or every time I have to do this:

```
for (i=0; i<count(productIds); i++)
      insertElement($companyId, $productIds[i])

function () insertElement($companyId, $productId) {

 $query = 'INSERT INTO CompanyProduct (companyId, productId) VALUES(:idA:, :idB:)';
            $result = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($query,
                [
                    'idA' => $companyId,
                    'idB' => $productId
                ]);
}
```

Comment: transaction is the way to go. if something goes wrong your data will be intact. you don't want to delete records then something happens and the new records doesn't go through. to give an optimal answer i need to see the ```CompanyProduct``` model code and the other models involved

Comment: btw you may want to close your previous question related to phalcon